# LINQ - MULTIPLE TABLES

Tags: linq-to-sql

**TABLE 1**:

TID:

TNAME:

TDESC:

**TABLE 2:**:

AID:

ANAME:

ADESC:

**TABLE 3**

TID:

AID:

How to write a Linq query to get list of table2 by passing TNAME in TABLE 1.:

Please help!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have the correct FK relationships in your database you just type

```
 from t2 in context.table2s
 where t2.table3.table1.TNAME == "SomeName"
 select t2
```

**Edit**
If you don't have foreigns in your database you can either "cheat" by drawing relations in the DBML designer or you need to resort to explicit joining

```
from t2 in context.table1s
join t3 in context.table3s 
    on t2.AID equals t3.AID
join t1 in context.table1s 
    on t3.TID equals t1.TID
where t1.TNAME == "SomeName"
select t2
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, my tables have the following relations:

Comment: It is just related as with the corresponding ids, but the query is not working for me.

Comment: @user669803, then you need to either create foreign keys in the database or at least in the DBML designer, as a final resort you can join explicitly as in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

you  need to use join. something like this

```
from t1 in db.Table1
join t2 in db.Table2 on t1.field equals t2.field
select new { t1.field2, t2.field3}
```

plz, chek [LinqJoin](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/JoinOperator.ashx)

Comment: Here i have an association table, in which it has only TID, using which I have to get the corresponding TNAME, so is it not like a Multiple join here.?